# replacing regular expressions with querying on and functions on match

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

EDIT: gave more context for my first approach.

My goal is to search my notes for strings of the form "4/1/2014" to org-mode timestamps "<2014-04-01 Wed>" (that particular day-of-week may be incorrect). I also want querying to be on so I do not accidentally do things like replacing part of a URL this way.

Assuming I already wrote a Day-of-the-week function (complaints welcome, though not part of the main question):

```
(defun dow (year month day)
  (interactive)
  (let ((encoded-time (encode-time 1 1 10 day month year)))
    (nth (nth 6 (decode-time encoded-time))
     '("Sun" "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"))))
```

I seem to be unable to do the rest. Here are my attempts and when they fall short:

1. First, I tried to use `query-replace-regexp`:

```
(defun date-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (query-replace-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)"
            "<\\3-\\1-\\2 \\,(dow (string-to-number \\3) (string-to-number \\1) (string-to-number \\2))>"))
```

I get an "invalid use of '\' in replacement text" error and do not know what to do with that even after googling; it seems the most likely cause is escaping something in the replacement string that's NOT '\', but I do none of that.

By the way, doing

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET \([0-9]+\)/\([0-9]+\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\) RET <\3-\1-\2 \,(dow (string-to-number \3) (string-to-number \1) (string-to-number \2))> RET
```

works, which is why I thought all I had to do was to escape the backslashes.

(another problem with this approach is it does not 0-pad 1-digit numbers in a way that seems clean to me, even if everything else were to work)

2. Then, I tried to use `search-forward-regexp`. Here's a clunky solution that works (replacing the relevant portion of above code):

```
(while (search-forward-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)" nil t)
  (let* ((ynum (string-to-number (match-string 3)))
       (mnum (string-to-number (match-string 1)))
       (dnum (string-to-number (match-string 2)))
       (dowstr (dow ynum mnum dnum)))
    (replace-match (format "<%04d-%02d-%02d %s>" ynum mnum dnum dowstr) t nil)))
```

The only problem here is that it **does not query,** and there does not seem to be flags that allow me to do that.

3. My final attempt is looking up `query-replace` and the manual suggesting using `perform-replace`. So here I have:

```
  (perform-replace "\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)"
           ((lambda (data numreps)
              (format "<%04d-%02d-%02d %s>" (nth 1 data) (nth 2 data) (nth 3 data)
                  (dow (nth 1 data) (nth 2 data) (nth 3 data))))
            .
            ((string-to-number (match-string 3))
             (string-to-number (match-string 1))
             (string-to-number (match-string 2))))
           t t t)
```

and I get "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" that I cannot decipher.

While my immediate goal is to find out which type of solution is the correct way to proceed and to make it work, I am overall more interested in why these bugs occur and how to get better at debugging, as I am new to learning elisp. Thanks!

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` if necessary.  Re that last error, you should be seeing a backtrace with `string-to-number(nil)` as the cause of that error, which obviously indicates that one of your `(string-to-number (match-string N))` instances was getting `nil` back from `match-string`.

Comment: ...which is presumably because you're evaluating that before any searching has taken place.  `(cons (lambda ...) ARG)` would be the format for the REPLACEMENTS part, and I presume ARG has to be something established at the point in time that the `perform-replace` is *called*.  It doesn't sound like it gets `eval`'d during the replacement process.

Comment: `nth` is indexed from zero, btw.

Comment: For `dow`, there is a builtin `calendar-day-of-week`: `(calendar-day-of-week '(1 31 2019)) ;; => 4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might write the `perform-replace` version like this:

```el
(perform-replace
 "\\b\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)\\b"
 (cons (lambda (&rest _)
         (let ((data (list (string-to-number (match-string 1))
                           (string-to-number (match-string 2))
                           (string-to-number (match-string 3)))))
           (format "<%04d-%02d-%02d %s>"
                   (nth 2 data) (nth 1 data) (nth 0 data)
                   (dow (nth 0 data) (nth 1 data) (nth 2 data)))))
       nil)
 t t nil)
```

Experimentally the DELIMITED arg doesn't behave as I'd expected.  I've set that `nil` and used `\b` explicitly in the regexp.  I'm sure there's a reason for that.  (Potentially when it says "surrounded by word boundaries" it *also* means "and containing only a single word", in which case the `/` instances would be the issue.)

---

The reason your `query-replace-regexp` attempt failed was that you expected that its arguments should look exactly the same as you enter them interactively; but in fact the `interactive` spec of that command manipulates what you enter into the format that it actually requires.

After performing the interactive command, you can use `repeat-complex-command` to learn what it actually did:

> ```
> C-x M-: runs the command repeat-complex-command (found in global-map),
> which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> It is bound to <again>, <redo>, C-x M-:, C-x M-ESC.
> ```

```el
(query-replace-regexp
 "\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]+\\)/\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)"
 (quote (replace-eval-replacement
         concat "<\\3-\\1-\\2 "
         (replace-quote (dow (string-to-number (match-string 3))
                             (string-to-number (match-string 1))
                             (string-to-number (match-string 2))))
         ">"))
 nil nil nil nil nil)
```

(All the optional `nil` args can, of course, be omitted.)

Comment: Thanks phils; not only for this answer but also teaching me how to fish above (esp. with the backtrace; I was only aware of looking at *messages* for errors). =) I guess I thought the (a . b) notation was supposed to cons.

Comment: The lisp reader *will* read `(a . b)` as a cons cell; but if `(a . b)` is *evaluated* it is a malformed function call, and hence an error, so one would *typically* be quoting that: `'(a . b)`, which then evaluates to the cons cell that was read.  It is *possible* to write and use unquoted dotted-pair notation, but it would be rather unusual to do so -- I think that using `(cons ...)` is invariably going to be more sensible.

Comment: e.g.: `((lambda . ((x . (y . ())) . ((message . ("%s, %s" . (x . (y . ()))))))) . ("Hello" . ("world." . ())))`